# Comparison: Esterification with acyl chloride and alcohol vs Fischer esterification

Tags: organic-chemistry, esters

I would like to know if there are more than mentioned pros and cons with the different methods in making an ester, and also ways to maximize product yield (comparing the two).

**Fischer**- **Pros**: cheap, easy, non-toxic (or less at least) to environment/laborants. **Cons**: worse yield and also slow

**Acyl chloride**- **Pros**: Faster, more yield. **Cons**: More dangerous, harder, and more expensive.

A way to maximize yield for Fisher esterification is to increase concentration to any reactants, alternative to remove the forming water.

I have not really found how I can maximize it for the acyl chloride-method however.

Comment: Depending on the reactants, Fisher esterification can also be inefficient giving rise to a range of side products from acid dehydration of the alcohol

Comment: Give Emil Fischer credit for his eponymous esterification, not Fisher.

Comment: The acyl chloride-primary alcohol reaction's yield should be near quantitative. The by-product, HCl, is a gas.